# PyJWT does not decode RS256 unencrypted token, Could not deserialize key data error

Tags: python, jwt, rsa, pyjwt

I am trying to decode a  JWT token. The token is signed but is not encrypted (so for instance it is decodeable by jwt.io webpage).

I have the dependency in `requirements.txt`: `PyJWT[crypto]==2.0.1`. Which supposed to install both PyJWT and cryptography library.

and I have the code like so

```py
decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, "", algorithms=["RS256"])
```

(RS256 returned by jwt.io when trying to decode it). So far I left `public key` parameter empty.

which currently generates an error

```
Error: Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format
or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm.
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: There are a bunch of options that can be passed to `jwt.decode` mentioned in the [docs](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=decode#jwt.decode) to specify decoding and validation options. `PyJWT` can decode `RS256` tokens.